# all data is not being read from excel file

Tags: c#, excel, ole

I am using the code below to read data from a excel sheet and add the data into a data sheet but when reading the file and inspecting the data in the data-table some of the data is missing.. I have been looking at this and have no idea why this would be the case.

```
excelConnectionString =
                  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
                      " ;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
            try
            {
                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                using (OleDbConnection connection =
                new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string[] excelSheet = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int sheet = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheet[sheet] = row["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        sheet++;

                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < excelSheet.Length; i++)
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                             ("Select  * FROM [" + excelSheet[i] + "]", connection);

                        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about the Data inside of Columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can reproduce your question and find out certain problem. But you can find the similar question here.

[Read Excel file through Datagridview](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/376355/import-MS-Excel-to-datatable)

[Export Excel to Datatable](http://excelcsharp.blog.com/2012/10/29/export-excel-to-datatable-and-import-datatable-to-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `OledbConnection` to read in Excel Files you will run into a problem where by the limit on characters for each column is 255.

You could try adding "IMEX=1;" to the end of you connection string, but I'm not sure that will solve your issue.

Comment: Is there more than 255 character in any of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `OleDbConnection` you will have the limitation of reading only 255 columns. I ran into this issue with big sheets and had to change the approach.

Link with a discussion about the issue:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0678e022-b435-4f47-a79c-73780301cfb3/using-ace-120-to-import-an-excel-worksheet-with-more-than-255-columns

It seems that's an old and known issue that will not be resolved for a while.